# Android Spinner: Cannot find Symbol R.styleable.Spinner_android_dropDownSelector

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using a custom spinner view. There were no issues while running with compile sdk 22. If I change compile sdk as 23 then run the app I am getting the following error. Below variables are removed from api 23. How can I resolve this?

> error: cannot find symbol
>   R.styleable.Spinner_android_dropDownVerticalOffset 
>   R.styleable.Spinner_android_dropDownSelector 
>   R.styleable.Spinner_android_dropDownHorizontalOffset

Answer (score 0):

You should update the "gradle version" and dependencies.

When we updates the SDK tools we should manually check the dependencies regarding to that SDK.

```
Select Project--> Righ Click-->Go To Open Module Settings-->Select dependencies--> select Library dependencies-->then check what is the current library versions are available for the your SDK--> select latest one.
```

if it is not working then update the gradle version also.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
}


dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'


    }
```